# PHP runtime cache

Tags: php, caching, runtime

I do not know if it's possible but I'd like to clear the runtime PHP class cache.

Assuming we have this simple code :

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
  public static $cache = array();

  public static function get($code)
  {
    self::$cache[$code] = $code;

    return self::$cache[$code];
  }

}
MyClass::get('myCode');

// do something

echo '<pre>';
print_r(MyClass::$cache);
echo '</pre>';
```

The print_r will show this array :

> Array
>   (
>       [myCode] => myCode
>   )

But 'id like to forget the runtime cache so the print_r shows an empty array.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `unset()` function?

Comment: unset can be used to unset an object. Here I don't have an object. My class is called statically. I could do unset(MyClass::$cache) but I have a lot of classes in my project. I'd like to clear the runtime cache for all classes at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function clean() 
{
    self::$cache = array();
}


MyClass::clean();
```